# I wanted some material or reource on how to make the web-applications autonomic

Tags: web-applications, cloud, envoyproxy, mesh-network

Autonomic computing everywhere describes about the computer system but I could not find resources where i can use autonomic computing in my web applications.
I wanted someone to suggest some material/book/resource where i can find how to implement autonomic computing in my web-apps.

I have deployed my application using docker and docker-compose and i have used envoy service mesh to get the metrics from each service. But i don't know how to use this metric data to achieve autonomicity.

no code

no errors

Comment: What does the question have to do with mesh networking?

Comment: Autonomic computing can use service mesh